# Linear Program with "Same Direction" Constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I have an optimization problem
$$ \min_{x, y, t} \left\{ f(x, y) : g(x, y) \ge 0, ~ x = t y, ~t \ge 0 \right\} $$
where $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t$ is some non-negative scalar. In other words, $x$ and $y$ are constrained to have equal direction. Is this constraint $x = t y$ inherently quadratic, or does anyone have some trick to express it in a linear form?

Comment: Maybe the following observation could help: Let $\mathbf x \in \mathbf P$ iff $A\mathbf x \leq \mathbf b$. Now, for any $t>0$ we have $\mathbf x \in t\mathbf P$ iff $\tfrac{1}{t}\mathbf x\in\mathbf P$ iff $A\tfrac{1}{t}\mathbf x \leq \mathbf b$. Since $t>0$ this is equivalent to $A\mathbf x \leq t\mathbf b$, i.e. $A\mathbf x - t\mathbf b \leq \mathbf 0$. The later is a system of linear inequalities. The case for $t=0$ is a little bit more complicated.